# With a given reward, what is the difference between reinforcement learning methods and relabel the data?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

If a clear reward is given, we can train the model by RL algorithm.

Or we can revise the label according to the reward and then retrain the model.

What is the difference, judged by the final result?

Comment: what is this "label", and how do you propose to revise it?

Comment: @shimao Thank you, I think if it is a 2-class classification problem, it is easy to revise it automatically. Otherwise we should revise it by human.